# Connecting AWS instance and godaddy domain name - issue with folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have XAMPP set up in an EC2 AWS instance and am trying to connect up my godaddy domain name. I can see xampp is working on the IP address and my site works under when I use IPADDRESS/FOLDER/index.php

How do I get my domain name to read the index.php file in the folder? All the tutorials I have followed allowed me to access an index file directly in the htdocs file (IPADDRESS/index.php) but I seem to be having trouble with the additional folder. The folder is important because it is managed with Git.

The folder I have saved in within my EC2 instance is /opt/lampp/htdocs/

Thank you!
Gemma

Answer (score 1):

You can't point a domain name to a folder. You need to edit your web server configuration on the EC2 server (Apache httpd?) to use the folder as the server root location.